# Nested if else statement, if 2nd if fails how to go to else?

Tags: javascript

I have a nested `if...else` block.

I would like to have an initial condition and if it passes the condition it should check the next condition. If the 2nd condition fails I'd like it to execute an else block.

Is it possible to do this with an `if...else` statement or should I be using something else?

Here's an example:

```
let x = 1;
let y = 2;
let z = 3;

if (x == 1) {
  console.log(x)
// the below statement would fail and I would like the else block to execute now, console.log(z)
  if (y == 3) {
    console.log(y)
  } 
} else {
  console.log(z);
}
```

EDIT:

My issue is the i need the same code to run if any of the 2 conditions fail and I can't figure out how to do this.

```
if (condition == true) {
  if (condition == true) {
    func1()
  } else {
   ApiCall1()
    }
  } else {
   ApiCall1()
 }
```

I've been told I can't create a function for `APiCall1`, I have to write it all out so I can't just copy and paste the code for `ApiCall1` in both blocks since it's 30 lines long. What should I do here?

Comment: if, else if, else

Comment: It is starting to sound like the if...else logic is not really important here, if your actual question is about the logic of handling API responses then I would close this question and start a new one solely about that. Remember that you are asking a question not only so that you solve your problem but that others find it and solve theirs, so it should be about one topic only - if...else or API handling

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe in your answer I believe you simply want to move your else block inside the block of the initial `if` statement (`if (x==1) {...}`)

Therefore:

```
if (x == 1) {
  console.log(x)
  if (y == 3) {
    console.log(y)
  }
  else {
    console.log(z);
  } 
}
```

Comment: If I reach that else statement it means all my API calls have failed. I'm not sure what I would put in that else block. Just `return`?

Comment: It depends, is it critical to your program that the API calls suceed?

Comment: Yes, without the API call succeeding the program won't function. I made an edit on my original post.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the other answers I'm not sure if you want to execute the `else` block if the first condition fails. If that is the case, then you could try:

```
if (x == 1 && y == 3) {
    console.log(x)
    console.log(y)
} else if (x == 1) {
    console.log(x)
} else {
    console.log(z)
}
```

You repeat some code, but I think there is no other way to do it, at least not one I can come up with.

EDIT:

After your edit, I think it makes even more sense this solution so that you have the code of your `ApiCall1` in the else block of my solution above.